# Adding users with hidden inputs using selection box in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to allow users to add other users on a form via a selection box. So, a user can select another user from a drop down selection, press add user, and they're added to an array. The user can select another user, and that second user should be added to this array. Right now, each time a user is added the original user disappears. I tried using hidden inputs but I'm not having any luck.

On formprocessing.php

```
 //this generates a list of users. The code to actually generate the users is omitted
 <center><h3>Invite Friends</h3></center><br>
     <form method="post">
     <tr><td>Friends:</td><td><select name ="friend"><Option value="">Friends<? echo $selection; ?></Select></td>
     <input type="hidden" name="hiddenFriends" value="<? echo $friends; ?>"/>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submitFriend" value="Add Friend"/>
     </form>
```

On form.php

```
//i'm trying to create an array of users which are added. When completed, they'll be added to the db
<?
if(isset($_POST['submitFriend'])){
    if(count($_POST['hiddenFriends']) > 0){
        $friend = $_POST['friend'];
        array_push($friends,$_POST['friend']);
    }
    else{
        $friends = array('');
        array_push($friends,$_POST['friend']);
    }
}
?><input type="hidden" name="hiddenFriends" value="<? echo $friends; ?>"/><?
print_r($friends);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude you trying to add PHP array into html input. Its **IMPOSSIBLE**.

but don't worry you can use explode and implode functions.

```
<?
$friends = array();
if(isset($_POST['submitFriend'])){

    if(strlen($_POST['hiddenFriends']) > 0){
        $friends = explode(',',$_POST['hiddenFriends']);                
    }    
    $friends[] = $_POST['friend'];
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenFriends" value="<? echo implode(',',$friends); ?>"/>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ... on line 333 which is the array_push($friends,$_POST['friend']) line. I echoed $_POST['friend'] and the value appears, so I know it's being sent.

Comment: No errors, but now it's back to my original issue. When I add a user, it shows the array 0=>2 (for example). If I add another user, instead of the array being 0=>2, 1=>3 it's just 0=>3. Basically the first user isn't "remembered" through the hidden value.

Comment: there was typo. "$friend = ..." should be $friends.use updated code, should work

Comment: It's partially working. The first spot in the array [0] is empty and throwing an error. Aside from that it works. I'm guessing it's starting the array at [1] for whatever reason. Any suggestions? **edit** - I changed it so if $friends is empty, place a '0' at the beginning. I know it's not good practice, but I'll just skip the 0 key when entering the info.

Comment: sorry i did some mistake in your question , i didn't run it by myself. now its work fine 100%.